# How to map tables without FK

Tags: postgresql, database-design, mapping

I have these tables:

- carWash
- order
- orderHistory
- user
- services

Connections: one `carWash` to many `orders`, one `order` to one `orderHistory`, one `carWash` to many `services`, one `user` to many `orders`

The question is: when user create order he choose some services that are provided by *car_wash* for example (wash_car_body = 20$, wash_wheels = 10$ ) from services table and when user wants to see order history I want to show all chosen services to user, how to do it better?

My services script:

```
create table services(
  id SERIAL not null,
  car_wash_id int not null, 
  name text not null,
  price double precision not null, 
  car_body text,

  CONSTRAINT "gmoika_service_company_id_fKey" FOREIGN KEY (car_wash_id)
      REFERENCES car_wash (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Car Wash Script:

```
create table services(
      id SERIAL not null,
      name text not null)
```

For example

```
insert into services (car_wash_id, price , name car_body) values (1,20,wheels_wash,sedan)
```

And when user create order to car_wash with id = `"id"` i use the following script to give him all services ,

```
select * from services s where s.car_wash_id = "id".
```

Then user choose services. And i want to save choosen services into order history.
OrderHistory script

```
CREATE TABLE order_history(
id SERIAL not null,
order_id int,
wash_price double precision,
car_body text,
box_number int,
car_wash_name text,
currency text,
time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
status text,
CONSTRAINT "gmoika_wash_history_id_fKey" FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
      REFERENCES order (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to query it already? You must be having some kind of link between the records otherwise it is not possible.. also try to give some sample data and a diagram of how the tablets are attachéd instead of in text.. this clears it up a lot

Comment: Add some explanations

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to add another table, e.g. `orderServiceHistory` which will be a mapping of `order_id` to `service_id`. Both of these will be foreign keys to the `order` & `services` tables. You could then use this to store which services were taken from a historic car wash order.

However, I'd recommend you think about your schema a bit more. Few things to consider off the top of my head:

1. Why the mix of plural and singular form (e.g. `order` vs `services`)
2. You haven't defined your primary keys
3. What is the purpose of the one to one mapping between `order` & `orderHistory`?
4. How would you handle when the price of a service changes?
5. How would the removal/inactivation of services & car washes etc be handled?